# TypeScript not recognizing string constants as object keys

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project using TypeScript 4.1.5, I'm not able to use an exported constant as an object key:

```
// my-module.constants.ts
export const STATE_KEY = 'state';

// my-module.ts
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      [STATE_KEY]: reducer,
    }),
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

I get an error:

> Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Expression form not
> supported.

Setting the key to the same string, but without square brackets works as expected. Has something changed in the syntax? I didn't notice anything in the TypeScript 4.1.5 release notes.

Comment: Pretty sure this is an Angular error and not a TypeScript one

Comment: Funny thing is the exact same code works just fine in other projects. I've restarted the VS Code TypeScript Server and restarted VS Code, but that doesn't help. Even dropping down to TypeScript 4.0.5 doesn't help.

Comment: Well yes... that's because it's not a TS error, so restarting the language server or changing TS versions won't help.

Comment: Hmm. I have other Angular projects using the *exact same versions* of Angular and Ngrx that use this syntax just fine.